# Where is std::cout defined?

Tags: c++, std

I would like to know how it works...

In the `<iostream>` header, there is `namespace std`:

```cpp
#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

namespace std {
  extern istream cin;
  extern ostream cout;
  extern ostream cerr;
  extern ostream clog;
  extern wistream wcin;
  extern wostream wcout;
  extern wostream wcerr;
  extern wostream wclog;
}
```

So, `cout` is the name of an object of type `ostream`, and that is defined in another file (due to `extern`). Ok.

When I tried in my simple program to create an `ostream` object, I can't, because the constructor of `ostream` class is `protected`. Ok.

So, how can I create (define) an object in an extern file, which has a `protected` constructor, and looks like a global variable?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout you can think about std::cout as a singleton. "These objects are guaranteed to be initialized during or before the first time an object of type std::ios_base::Init is constructed and are available for use in the constructors and destructors of static objects with ordered initialization (as long as <iostream> is included before the object is defined)."

Comment: `In iostream header there is namespace std:` Are you browsing libstdc++? Is there no license information on top of that file?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, there is information about license. But what this change? I would like only to know how can I create something simillar to cout.

Comment: Exactly when, where and *how* the standard stream objects are defined is an implementation detail that is irrelevant to their usage. If you have a specific problem creating your own stream objects then please ask about that directly instead.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi Thank you for answer. I know that I can think about cout as a singleton. But still don't have idea how can I create simillar thing in my project. I know how can I create singleton, but when I would like for example write something I have to write getSingleton()<<"Hello World!". I would like to avoid ()

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For example I would like to have library like iostream, where there is namespace and there are object of other classes ( like cout, cin, clog ). I would like to use them like cout, so no defined it on my program, but write only cout<<"something" and I would like to block create object of that class in my program ( co constructor has to be protected / private ).

Comment: The C++ standard library has a bunch of headers and a binary library (libstdc++ in case of gcc, libc++ for clang), the actual cout object is most likely in the binary part. [Yep, there it is.](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/ios_init.cc) with a placement new using the explicit constructor and [storage defined here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/globals_io.cc).

Comment: Which constructor did you try to use? There is one public c'tor in the spec https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How libstdc++ used by gcc does it:

Storage for `cout` is defined as a global variable of type `fake_ostream` which is presumably constructible without problems.
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/globals_io.cc

Then during library initialization rewritten with a placement new using the explicit constructor.
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/ios_init.cc

Other compilers have their own libraries and may use different tricks. Examining the source of libc++ used by clang left as exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is perfect, but I still don't get it. I see that there is created new type ( this is char[sizeof(ostream)] ) and next there is defined new object ( name cout ) using that new type. In other file there is declared cout using extern, but with type... ostream. How? When I tried do this I get error "redeclaration of xxxx ( my object name ) with different type: std:ostream vs char[272]"

Comment: @juga92 I think that's what the comment `Iff <iostream> is included, these definitions become wonky` in globals_io.cc is about. The real declaration (extern ostream cout) and the fake definition (fake_ostream cout) should not meet in one compilation unit. And if you have defined something called cout with the right size in one file and another file is asking for an extern cout, the linker will connect those two. For data, only names are checked during linking, there is no way to compare types.

Comment: I'm sure if you search for "compilation and linking C++", there are better explanations than mine. With pictures...